# app-only rights to create sitecollections

Tags: sharepoint-addin, patterns-and-practices, pnp

I'm using the PnP framework and want to do a app-only authentication against the mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com site so I can create sitecollection but I dont know how to give the app rights to the admin site.

In normal cases I'm going to the page _/layouts/15/appinv.aspx to give app-permission rights but that does not work from admin site.

How am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register your app only principal using your regular root site collection https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx and appinv.aspx (you don't need to do this on the mytenant-admin site)

You will need to have tenant admin rights, and use the following permissions xml in appinv.aspx

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
 </AppPermissionRequests>
```

However in your app code, when you get your app-only access token and client context, you need to use the mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com site url.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot this really solved my problems.